# "Add dependency on module [project].main" for custom sourceset

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

This is derived from a bug I just filed on IntJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-302732/Gradle-wrapper-builds-jar-from-custom-source-set-without-error-but-intelliJ-fails-import

I don't think it is a real problem in the sense that all this works with gradle, but it produces spurious errors in IntJ and, until the bug (if it be) is fixed, I'm looking for a way around. It *could* be derived from some unconventional practice of mine, so if you see anything that makes you think "there's a more conventional method here", let me know.

I'm using a custom sourceset to build an executable jar in a library project; it's for a tool that uses the lib but isn't included in it.  I know other people use a similar method for demos and integration tests.

I put together a minimal example for the bug report, here's the meat of `build.gradle.kts` (the whole thing is posted in the report if you want/need):

```
sourceSets["main"].java.srcDir("src")
sourceSets.create("eg") {
    java.srcDirs("src", "eg")
    compileClasspath = sourceSets["main"].compileClasspath
}

tasks.register<Jar>("foobar") {
    archiveFileName.set("foobar.jar")
    manifest { attributes["Main-Class"] = "FoobarKt" }
    // Not sure why this is necessary here, it isn't in the original project.
    duplicatesStrategy = org.gradle.api.file.DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from(sourceSets["eg"].output)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter {
            it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })
}
```

src/main/kotlin/Example/Example.kt:

```
package Example

class Example {
    fun hello () {
        println("hello world")
    }
}
```

And in eg/Foobar.kt, the entry point for the executable jar:

```
import Example.Example

fun main () {
    val eg = Example()
    eg.hello()
}
```

If I run `./gradlew foobar` from the project directory, it builds without error and runs via `java -jar` as expected.

However, in the IntJ editor, Foobar.kt has "unresolved reference" errors for `Example` on lines  1 and 4.  It suggests I "Add dependency on module Problem.main", which is clickable but does nothing.<sup>1</sup>

I admit to not being much of a gradle fan -- for whatever reason the supposedly (?) intuitive DSL is persistently counter-intuitive with me, I'd much rather just use a more normal API (if the build system is going to be Turing complete, why dress it down inscrutably?) -- and I just don't get what is meant by that.

---

1. There's a slew of other reports going back for years about this "add dependency on module..." suggestion doing nothing in various contexts.

Comment: Has been filled as a bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-302732

Comment: Thanks for your reply there, I have incorporated it into an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000323/andrey) for posting a solution in the bug report. Whether it remains a bug to be fixed or an inconsistency to be noted is up to others, but what works is to add the `output` of the main sourceset to the `compileClasspath` in the definition of the custom one:

```
sourceSets.create("eg") {
    java.srcDirs("src", "eg")
    compileClasspath = sourceSets["main"].compileClasspath
    // You can use '+' as well to combine these in one line.
    compileClasspath += sourceSets["main"].output
}
```

You actually only need the `output` to resolve the problem in the example from the question here, but if the custom sourceset code includes imports of project dependencies declared with `implementation` or `api`, you need
the main `compileClasspath` as well.